# Python indentation error when documenting the code

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code in Python.

```
"""
====================================================
This file provides a wrapper around the WebPageTest
APIs for starting a test and generating a har file
====================================================
"""

import json, urllib, os, ConfigParser
from pprint import pprint
from webPageTestConfigUtils import WebPageTestConfigUtils

class WebPageTestProcessor:

"""
=====================================================
Method to submit a test to WPT. Takes a url as input
for which you want to run the test.
=====================================================
"""
    def submitTest(self,url):
        response = None
        if url is not None:
            wptUrl = WebPageTestConfigUtils.getConfigValue('runTestURL')+"?f=json&url="+url+"&runs=3&video=1&web10=0&fvonly=1&mv=1&private=1&location=us_east_wptdriver:Chrome.DSL"
            response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(wptUrl))
            return response["data"]["testId"]

"""
======================================================
Method to check the status of the test submitted.
Takes a testId as input.
======================================================
"""
    def checkTestStatus(self,testId):
        response = None
        if testId is not None:
            wptUrl = WebPageTestConfigUtils.getConfigValue('testStatusURL')+"?f=json&test="+testId
            response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(wptUrl))
            return response
"""
======================================================
Method to get the HAR file. Takes the filepath to a
destination file and a testId for which to get a HAR.
Make sure you have write permissions to the file.
======================================================
"""
    def getHarFile(self,filePath, testId):
        if ( filePath is not None and testId is not None):
            harUrl = WebPageTestConfigUtils.getConfigValue('harFileURL')+"?test="+testId
            urllib.urlretrieve(harUrl,filePath)
```

I am getting an error

`IndentationError: expected an indented block` near

```
"""
=====================================================
Method to submit a test to WPT. Takes a url as input
for which you want to run the test.
=====================================================
"""
```

Why is that error coming since I have indented the code correctly

Comment: Argh, my eyes! Please read [PEP-0257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) (I am partial to the [Google style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html)). See the [style guide, PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), too; those `import` lines are non-compliant for a start.

Comment: class `docstring` must be with in class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated

As @PM 2Ring pointed out, it was meant to say docstring as in OP, with additional information: Comments are treated as whitespace, and don't have to align with the indentation.

Even the **docstrings** have to be indented as error suggests:

```
class WebPageTestProcessor:

    """
    =====================================================
    Method to submit a test to WPT. Takes a url as input
    for which you want to run the test.
    =====================================================
    """
    def submitTest(self,url):
        response = None
        if url is not None:
            wptUrl = WebPageTestConfigUtils.getConfigValue('runTestURL')+"?f=json&url="+url+"&runs=3&video=1&web10=0&fvonly=1&mv=1&private=1&location=us_east_wptdriver:Chrome.DSL"
            response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(wptUrl))
            return response["data"]["testId"]
```

...

Comment: Docstrings are **NOT** mere comments! They are real live _code_! Comments are treated as whitespace, and don't have to align with the indentation. It's nice if they do, but try telling that to some editor's auto-commenting features. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring, I was meant to say docstring, just got mixed up in my head, answer edited. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter doc string in tab. You cant add at same level class starts

```
class ABC:
    """ 
    DOC STRING
    """
    ....
    def xyz(self):
        """
        DOC STRING FOR FUNCTION
        """
        ...
```